# What is the best way to develop a database in a python script and use the database in another python script (Django app) at the same time?

Tags: python, django, database

I have a python script that does several analysis and develop and update a database on a regular basis non-stop.
On the other hand, I am using a Django application to show the database online.
What is your suggestion for the best way to shake hands between these two parts?
I think of a simple text file or CSV file, but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have two ideas for you.**

1. **Django can access multiple different databases at at time**

If your database can easily be connected to your Django app, then you could just connect it directly. For more information, take a look at the official documentation on this topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/. You are talking about using a CSV file, so I assume that these apps are running on the same server, which is why this choice would probably make the most sense.

2. **A microservice**

In my job, I build deployable machine learning projects. That requires a database which holds the models and the data for the models as well as a database that handles all the user management, accounts, email information, etc. What we do there is attach a Flask app that just allows us to query the ML database as required from the main Django app.

Comment: Dear Mathew, Thank you for sharing your experience. For now, both codes are on the same server. And, my project is somehow similar to your job, I have a DNN algorithm working along with a ML algorithm for evaluating some geospatial parameters. And Django is going to represent the data on a map on the website. So, do you think that I can work with Django app database directly, and at the same time I can make changes to the database by the other code?